# Hide friending activity from Timeline by default

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy, friends

Whenever I get a new friend on Facebook, a new entry appears in Activity Log with a pencil icon. Clicking this pencil icon reveals that it is "*Allowed on Timeline*". I would like to make it "*Hidden from Timeline*" **by default**, without having to come fix it after every friending.

[image: became friends with]

- That menu used to have a "*Hide Similar Activity from Timeline*", but not anymore.
- The [Privacy](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy) and [Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=timeline) settings don't seem to have anything about friending activity.